# Python 2.7 variable type stays as int32 instead of converting to long

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to decode a list of boolean values **into** numbers **via bitwise** shifting operations in a for loop. This is a simplified example of my code:

```
import numpy as np
k = 0
m = np.full((1, 32), True, dtype=bool)    # example list
n = m[0]
for i in n:
    k = k << 1 | i

print (k)
```

However, *k* returns as `-1` instead of `4294967295`. Running this in a debugger shows that *k* is **of type int32**. Is there anyway to force *k* to be a long type instead? Or is there an alternative way to decode my list of booleans. The code should handle up to 128 bits. I'm wondering if this only happens in a for loop since shifting more than 32 bits outside of the loop seem to work fine.

Using `k = 0L` gives correct value for my example code, but it only changes the type to `int64` and does not work for boolean lists longer than 64.

Comment: `k = 0L` might help. it makes a k a long from the start. Also this sounds like it could be a problem of [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: I have tested your code (on both Python 2.7 and 3.7) and it prints the expected value of 4294967295. So, I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @alec_djinn I'm getting output -1 in python 3.6.4

Comment: @DavidZemens I have tried with Python 3.6 as well, nothing changes. I am getting the right value out. Could it be an OS problem? I am on macOS Sierra.

Comment: @meissner_  I tried your suggestion on both my actual code and the example code. k = 0L gives correct value, but only changes the variable to type int64 which is not good enough for my purposes for when my lists are 128 elements or more.

Comment: @meissner_ I'm also getting out of -1 on 2.7.1. Both are Windows OS.

Comment: But I get correct value out from 2.7 if I do `k = 0L`.

Comment: @DeeLoon: oh ... well if you really need 128bit integers you'll have to use ctypes i guess. `import ctypes` and `k = ctypes.c_longlong()` might just do the trick.

Comment: @DavidZemens Is your OS at 32bit? I don't see otherwise why the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling about I got my code working the way I wanted. Turns out all I had to do was **cast the bitwise operation into a `long` type**. Problem seems to be that the bitwise operator kept returning `int32` or `int64` types. This is only for Python 2.7

```
import numpy as np
k = 0
m = np.full((1, 129), True, dtype=bool)    # example list
n = m[0]
for i in n:
    k = long((k << 1 )| i)

print (k)    # should give '680564733841876926926749214863536422911'
```